# Phonegap app that should work offline by using data from existing data i.e.,xml,csv etc

Tags: android, xml, html, cordova, csv

I am working on a hybrid application that receives information like name,dob etc from the user.

These are the input constraints. when user enters these details .
I have a sample data to display his horoscope *everyday based on his name,dob*(I have that algorithm that calculates his sunsign)

**So, The data is  something like this:
 if sunsign="A" then on "23/5/15" your horoscope is "..................."
 
                         "24/5/15" your horoscope will be "................"

I have data for whole year on every sunsign.

Al the above data has to be displayed only if the user sunsign is "A".

```
 <----index.html----->
<input type ="text" Placeholder="username" />
<p>Date of Birth </p> <input type="date" />
<button>submit</button>
<---On click submit button his sunsign will be decided---><br>
<---Navigate the page to next page--->
```

Page 2.

This page should display information of user based on the sunsign.

This app should work also offline. What is the approach that I should use in order to retrieve the data from some file(xml or csv or something)?.

Howe where to store all this data and how to retrieve it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in:

1. Cookie (i. if you host the html in web server.  ii. if your client use iphone.  iii. android phone webview does not support cookie)
2. localStorage (for simple storage only, e.g. string)
3. cordova File API (some mobile phones does not work as expected, e.g. Samsung Note 2, sometimes RequestFileSystem does not work)
4. client side sqlite

Using one of the above, your app should work offline.

To conclude, the Read data and Display Data should be done separately!  Every time you read data from the internet, from any server, from web api, or from any file, put the data into the client side [local storage].

Then, every time you display data, read from your local storage.

Try to add a timer to read new data when the client is online.

Or, like my apps, I use SIGNRALR server to notify my mobile phone clients when there is new data available.

Comment: Yes Mr.@Kenneth Li,  
i donot want to maintain server for this application rather i will update this app every year by replacing the exising data file with same name but with different content . What file system should i make use of? If any please let me know how can i do that with a small example .Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can simply use the Cordova File API.  example can be found at: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html

Comment: Or use local storage, for example:    window.localStorage.setItem("VariableName", "VariableValue");   to set a value and    tempString = window.localStorage.getItem("VariableName");      after running these 2 javascript in the app, tempString = "VariableValue"